# Easy Way to Convert iterate JSON Array with duplicates and create new JSON Array with same Old JSON elements and an extra field in each element

Tags: arrays, json

I want to convert a duplicate JSON Array to unique JSON Array and want another param in new JSON each element  {repeated:}

```
    duplicateJSON =[{id:"1",name:"test1"},{id:"2",name:"test2"},{id:"1",name:"test1"},{id:"2",name:"test2"},{id:"3",name:"test3"}]
```

Need to form another JSON with below requirement

```
uniqueJSON=[{id:"1",name:"test1",repeated:2},{id:"2",name:"test2",repeated:2},{id:"3",name:"test3",repeated:1}
```

I don't want any duplicates in the output just need to get repeated count

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
    const arr = [
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1007",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
  {
    partNum: "ACDC1009",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },

  {
    partNum: "ACDC1000",
    brandName: "Electric",
    supplierName: "Electric",
  },
];

const countDict = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { partNum } = curr;
  if (acc[partNum]) ++acc[partNum];
  else acc[partNum] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = arr.map((obj) => {
  obj["count"] = countDict[obj.partNum];
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

results in:

```
[
  {
    "partNum": "ACDC1007",
    "brandName": "Electric",
    "supplierName": "Electric",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "partNum": "ACDC1007",
    "brandName": "Electric",
    "supplierName": "Electric",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "partNum": "ACDC1007",
    "brandName": "Electric",
    "supplierName": "Electric",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "partNum": "ACDC1009",
    "brandName": "Electric",
    "supplierName": "Electric",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "partNum": "ACDC1000",
    "brandName": "Electric",
    "supplierName": "Electric",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to remove duplicate items from the Array of objects:

```js
let duplicateJSON = [
  { id: '1', name: 'test1' },
  { id: '2', name: 'test2' },
  { id: '1', name: 'test1' },
  { id: '2', name: 'test2' },
  { id: '3', name: 'test3' },
];

let uniqueJSON = [... new Map(duplicateJSON.map((item)=>[item["id"], item])).values()]
console.log(uniqueJSON);
```